# How to Upload Data to Azure Storage in chunks/blocks?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading images to Azure Storage, and need to implement chunking to upload heavy image.
But I'm getting exception such as "Offset and length out of bound"

```
int fileSize = imageModel.ImageByteArray.Length;
int blockSize = 100*1024 , numberOfBlocks = 0;

if (fileSize < blockSize)
    blockSize = fileSize;

if (fileSize % blockSize == 0)
    numberOfBlocks = fileSize / blockSize;
else
    numberOfBlocks = fileSize / blockSize + 1;

byte[] blockArray = new byte[blockSize];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(imageModel.ImageByteArray, i * blockSize, blockArray, 0, blockSize);
    await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(blockArray, i, imageModel.ImageByteArray.Length);
    Progress = (float)i / numberOfBlocks;
}

var ResponseURL = blob.Uri.OriginalString;
```

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This code *always* copies `blockSize` bytes:

```
Array.Copy(imageModel.ImageByteArray, i * blockSize, blockArray, 0, blockSize);
```

However, the last block may not be a full `blockSize`:

```
if (fileSize % blockSize == 0)
    numberOfBlocks = fileSize / blockSize;
else
    numberOfBlocks = fileSize / blockSize + 1;
```

To fix this, you'll need to handle the last block specially. It may be a full `blockSize` bytes or it may be less.

Comment: That can be handled , but to upload in chunks , I dont think this is the way, Thats what I want to know

Comment: It will still work in chunks; I'm saying the size of the last chunk may be different than the others.